# Как записать в массив теги, атрибуты и имена атрибутов?

Tags: c#, xml

Есть код, он выписывает теги, атрибуты и имена атрибутов:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\mgpi-driver.conf");
    PrintElementV2(doc);
    Console.ReadKey();
}       

static void PrintElementV2(XDocument doc)
{
    foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Elements())
    {
        my_recursive_function(element);
    }
}

static void my_recursive_function(XElement element)
{
    Console.WriteLine("tagName: {0}", element.Name);
    foreach (XAttribute attr1 in element.Attributes())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("attrName: {0}", attr1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("attrValue: {0}", attr1.Value);
    }
    foreach (XElement second_level_element in element.Elements())
    {
        my_recursive_function(second_level_element);
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Как мне записать в массив всё это?

Comment: Что мешает передавать не только XElement element, но еще и массив?

Comment: Мне мешают достаточных знаний по c#

Comment: А какую структуру массива вы хотите получить? Или просто записать все строки выводимые в консоль ещё и в массив?

Comment: Да , чтоб и в консоль и в массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например вот так:

```
List<string> ConfigLinesList=new List<string>();
```

Объявление ConfigLinesList разместите в теле метода или глобально в классе (в зависимости от того, какая область видимости данного списка вам нужна)

И после каждого вызова `Console.WriteLine(...)`
добавить `ConfigLinesList.Add(String.Format(...));` Где вместо троеточия передавать ту же строку что и в `Console.WriteLine` строчкой выше.

Так же имеет смысл в PrintElementV2 вызывать `ConfigLinesList.Clear()` Если список имеет глобальную область видимости.

Comment: Начинаю вставлять что у меня после Console.WriteLine Пишет что: ни одна из перезагрузок add не принимает 2 аргументов

Comment: Скорректировал ответ